How to configure advancedio function endpoint to the Custom User validation in Zoho Catalyst authentication?
I have an advancedio function in my local machine created for my Catalyst project. I have configured embedded authentication and looking to enable Custom User Validation for my project.
When I select the dropdowns, I am not be able to select my advancedio function. How to configure an advancedio function endpoint for the custom user validation in Catalyst console?

You will only be able to map a basicio function for the custom user validation in Catalyst. You can create a separate basicio function for your project and paste the code here in your function.
The basicio function will be automatically triggered upon every new user signup and check the email against your function logic. If the email is genuine, you can add the user to your application and if not you can restrict the user in signing up your application.
